# Как предотвратить срабатывание события click на <html> при зажатии кнопки мыши над <input> и отпускании над <html>?

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';
document.documentElement.onclick = function() {
    console.log('click on html');
}
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('click on input');
}
```

```html
<input id='foo'>
```

Comment: А почему бы не проверять фокус, а не клик?

Comment: С событием focus код будет выполнятся сразу по клику, а не после отпускания мышки

Comment: А финальная цель в чем? @RedWoolf Клик и есть "отпускание мыши" ) Сначала выполняется mousedown, потом mouseup, потом click.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Цель: click на <html> удаляет <input>. Выделяя текст в <input> часто отпускаешь кнопку мыши за его пределами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
'use strict';

let flag = false;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
  flag = (e.target.tagName == "HTML"); // Сразу будет получать true или false
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let tag = e.target.tagName;
  
  if( !flag && tag == "HTML" ) {
    // Если зажали мышку НЕ на HTML, но отпустили на нем - разворачиваемся.
    console.log( 'Я тучка, а вовсе не медведь!' );
    return;
  }
  
  if( flag ) {
    console.log( '<html> clicked!' );
  } else {
    console.log( tag + ' clicked!' );
  }
});
```

```html
<input id='foo'>
```

Comment: Маленькая неточность. Если зажать на `<html>` и отпустить на `<input>` то выведется: `<html> clicked!`. Возможно будет лучше: `if (tag == "HTML") {if (flag) {...} else {...}} else {...}`. В любом случае идея с `mousedown` понятна.